# What does ramp mean in the context of quantum control/pulse shape?

Tags: quantum-control

In the caption of Fig. 2 in [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep12430), there's the phrase 'fixed ramp', which I don't know the meaning and couldn't find any relevant explanation in quantum computing literature. There's description in the corresponding paragraph but didn't explain what they exactly did by 'ramping'. I guess it's something in electronic engineering but I couldn't find valid keywords to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ramp up (or down) is just a gradual increase (cq. decrease) of a signal. By 'fixed' I think they just mean at a fixed rate, i.e. linear.

See also:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave